# Opening google hangouts or another voip based sms app from browser links

Tags: sms, google, google-hangouts, google-voice

My work requires me to text a number of people with a preset text message(ETA for their deliveries). We have a sms: link for each customer which automatically opens the sms app and pre-fills the number and the text message.

Problem is that I have a data-only plan on my phone and use google voice for everything. GV (hangouts app) can be set to open the sms: links but currently it redirects to default sms app after showing an error message about hangouts no longer supporting sms. Even though it does support it for GV users!

So I am looking for a workaround or another app that can allow me to click a sms: link and send the message via GV or it's own sms service.

I've tried things like [2ndLine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enflick.android.tn2ndLine&hl=en) and [Fongo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fongo.dellvoice) but they can either not be set as default sms app or can't handle sms links.

EDIT: I've got control over how the sms links are created. So if changing the format of the link can solve this then that is an option as well. 
Currently the links look like --

`<a href="sms:+17777777777?&body=some text message">Send sms</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, but still welcome other better/easier to implement solutions.

There is an app - [xvoiceplus](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.runnirr.xvoiceplus) that can make third party apps use gv for sms. This should do the trick for me however it requires xposed framework which in turn requires the phone to be rooted.

Installation instructions [here](http://www.droidviews.com/use-google-voice-with-3rd-party-messaging-apps/)